# Purpose of UNION and BIND in WHERE clause, implementing auto-numbering

Tags: sparql

I am trying to implement increment/decrement using sparql/sesame query. I came across [How to model consecutive numbering without transactions?](https://web.archive.org/web/20130901050540/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17389/how-to-model-consecutive-numbering-without-transactions), which proposes this query:

```
INSERT {
    _:ex a ex:Invoice ;
         ex:number ?next .
}
WHERE {
    {
        SELECT ((MAX(?number) + 1) AS ?next)
        WHERE {
            { ?x ex:number ?number ;
                 a ex:Invoice }
            UNION
            { BIND (0 AS ?number) }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand the purpose of `union` in the `where` clause. What is happening in `where` clause and with the `bind`?  Is the value bound by `bind` used as a default if there is no triple present for it, meaning that `0` will be the first number?

EDIT:FOLLOW-UP:

Quick clarification....the query in my post (with coalesce) will insert multiple rows (which was the intent of that query). How can I modify that query to just increment/decrement 1 row?? If I add DELETE before insert, then what ld be the behavior? would the ?next be deleted before its selected???/

```
DELETE {
    _:ex a ex:Invoice ;
         ex:number ?object .
}
INSERT {
    _:ex a ex:Invoice ;
         ex:number ?next .
}
WHERE {
    {
        SELECT ((MAX(?number) + 1) AS ?next)
        WHERE {
            { ?x ex:number ?number ;
                 a ex:Invoice }
            UNION
            { BIND (0 AS ?number) }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I use query above to just increment 1 row and for the first time insert a row with value 0??

Comment: Just in case you're using something like that solution, I just posted [an answer](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17389/how-to-model-consecutive-numbering-without-transactions/24662) on that question too;  you can use the much simpler `select (coalesce(max(?number),0)+1 as ?next) where { … }` instead of this UNION pattern.  That says "`?next` is one plus (`max(?number)` if it's not an error, and `0` otherwise)".  You don't have to make the engine to a UNION at all.

Comment: Quick clarification....the query in my post (with coalesce) will insert multiple rows (which was the intent of that query). How can I modify that query to just increment/decrement 1 row?? If I add DELETE before insert, then what ld be the behavior? would the ?next be deleted before its selected???/

Comment: Since ?object is only mentioned in the delete, doesn't your delete everything? The select query I posted should only return one row, so only one instance of the insert pattern should be inserted, I'd think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

What happens is that both arguments of the union provide a solution (the second arg always providing 0), and then the MAX in the projection makes sure that the highest number is chosen. Thus in most cases the second UNION argument does effectively nothing. However, in the case where the first argument does not provide a solution (because no invoice number is present yet), only the second argument will provide a solution and this will be picked as the max and then inserted (+1) as the first number.